# Is it possible to keep controlling bandwidth in a wireless router that is now used only as access point?

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, bandwidth

I have a wifi router (TP-LINK WR740n) which is able to control bandwidth to avoid problems between gamers and torrent and streaming video users.
*All users connections are wireless. Also, there is no "internal" traffic - between users.*
Unfortunately, its WAN port is not working anymore due to a lightning rain.
On the other hand, it could still work as just an access point and could provide internet connection through one of its LAN ports.

Will it still be able to control bandwidth? Or, **does the traffic need to go through WAN to be controlled?**

Another possibility would be to use WDS mode instead of a LAN port, but I suppose the wireless router is probably even less prone to control the bandwidth of the clients (that will appear as clients of the master WDS).

Comment: One key information is missing: Are the gamers connected to LAN or WiFi. If the device's architecture is relatively reasonable, traffic control is at least possible for bridge functionality, and WiFI <-> LAN is always a bridge. Of course, the UI may limit the functionality to the WiFI <-> WAN bridge. Otherwise, if gamers are connected via LAN, you would have to be able to re-group bridged LAN ports and establish a software bridge between the gamers and the "uplink". Otherwise, all LAN ports are a bridge, assuming they're all in the same subnet, so no need for filtering, right?

Comment: Hint: With many ASUS routers, you can re-group the LAN ports and establish VLANs, bridges, QOS and such, but only on the command line interface. -- I'm writing this for you to know what to look for; I don't know the device and chances are that you need to dig deeply into forums. But many TP-LINK devices are based on pretty powerful software.

Comment: @Class Stacker All users connections are wireless. Also, there is no activity between users.

Comment: This particular router requires the WAN port to utilize things like QoS. I have one myself, and I use it as accesspoint too, and the QoS etc is not working there either. QoS is a function of NAT translation in this router it seems.

Comment: @LPChip That sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: @LPChip Good to know. Does it also apply to the WDS funcionality, i.e. to use the equipment as a repeater and band controler?

Comment: Any other form of control is all part of NAT translation. Bandwidth, QoS, PortForwarding, etc. All the router is now, is a switch and accesspoint.

Comment: WDS should still work, but I have no other WDS device here to test it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this particular model (I have one myself) all features you talk about, QoS, Bandwidth, Portforwarding, etc are part of NAT translating. This means that it only works with traffic directed from and to the WAN port.

With this port out of business, all your router is, is a switch and access point.

Features specifically designed for either of these should still work in theory, such as WDS, but I am not able to test that myself.